# Return multiple values from array when if condition satisfies multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, if-statement

I want to  return multiple values from for loop and if my condition satisfies more than one time

```
for(var i=0;i<graphVariableCount;i++)
  {
     if(commandResponse.GenericName == graphVariables[i].variable.index)
     {
        return graphVariables[i].variable.index;
     }
  }
```

In above code i am able to return only one value. If GenericName of graphVariable[i].variable.index is same for 4-5 variables. Then how am i able to return that values.

Comment: you can use an array to save your data each time it pass the condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `filter` and `map`

```
return graphVariables.filter( s => commandResponse.GenericName == s.variable.index )
               .map( s => s.variable.index );
```

**Explanation**

- `filter` will filter the array to get only matching values
- `map` will iterate that filtered array and get only `s.variable.index` from the same.

Comment: @RajeshRamtere Use this instead of your entire for-loop

Comment: This is also assuming that you can use arrow notation (older browsers like IE don't support arrow notation) and that this isn't work that will look weird because the code provided is more vanilla JS and the guru provided newer syntax that will stick out like a sore thumb.

Answer (score 2):

```
   var values = [];
   for(var i=0;i<graphVariableCount;i++)
      {
         if(commandResponse.GenericName == graphVariables[i].variable.index)
         {
            values.push(graphVariables[i].variable.index);
         }
      }  
   return values;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use temperory as below:

```
var results= []; 
for(var i=0;i<graphVariableCount;i++)

  {

     if(commandResponse.GenericName == graphVariables[i].variable.index)
     {
       results.push( graphVariables[i].variable.index);
     }
  }
```